# Implement Map function in APL Language

Tags: apl

I have created the `map` function using `Scheme`, but I want to implement it in `APL`.

```
(define (map func lstt)
 (cond
 ((null? lst) '())
 (else (cons (func (car lst))
 (map func (cdr lst))))
 )
)
```

The `map` function takes `two arguments`: a function: `func` (like `double: *2`) and list of integers: `lst`

Calling `map` with `double (*2)` and `list (1 2 3)` will result in `list (2 4 6)`

Any help to implement it in `APL`

Comment: APL implementations vary a bit. It would have to state which one you use, e.g. APL2, APLX, Dyalog APL, GNU APL, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Map is doubly built into APL:

1. Every arithmetic function have an implicit `map`:

   ```
   double←×∘2
   double 1 2 3
   4 5 6
   ```
2. A general purpose `map` is also built in, namely `¨`:

   ```
   reverse←⌽
   reverse 'abc' 'def' 'ghi'
   ┌───┬───┬───┐
   │ghi│def│abc│
   └───┴───┴───┘
   reverse¨'abc' 'def' 'ghi'
   ┌───┬───┬───┐
   │cba│fed│ihg│
   └───┴───┴───┘
   ```

That said, you can define `map` recursively as in your example code. For simplicity, let's restrict the domain to lists:

```
map←{0=≢⍵:⍵ ⋄ (⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵),∇1↓⍵}
reverse map 'abc' 'def' 'ghi'
┌───┬───┬───┐
│cba│fed│ihg│
└───┴───┴───┘
```

This is how it works:

`map←{`…`⍺⍺`…`}` defines `map` to be a [monadic operator](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Monadic_operator)

`0=≢⍵:` if the argument has no elements (zero equals the tally of the argument)

`⍵` return the argument

`⋄` else

`(⊂⍺⍺⊃⍵)` open up the first element, apply the function and close it again

`,∇1↓⍵` concatenated with recursion the rest of the argument (one element dropped from the argument)

Comment: thaaaanks a lot genius